# deformable and variable text on a mesh in unity

Tags: unity, models, text

So I am working on a sports game and I want the jerseys to be customizables with names and numbers. I have the character models as a single mesh however I can't place a text on the back of the jersey for the player to customize. I've found that unity has a Text Mesh, however it is not deformable. When the player runs, the number and name instead of being glued to the shirt actually appear more as a sign attached to the avatar's back. How can I do this text on the players jerseys, that can change its value via user input and to have the properties of the shirt object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the text through the material which is applied to the player.
There are numerous ways to do this.

1) By code write the player's name and number on the shirt image , and then reapply it to the material.mainTexture for the player's mesh. (This has a downside tho :P)

2) Another way is to have an additional transparent rectangular mesh on the back which gets deformed exactly as the the shirt mesh. Then add the players number and name to that material. Note: The material should be transparent cutout.

3) Decals also works great , generally used as a overlaying texture over a mesh to illustrate dirt or wearing . You can apply name and number decals to the shirt material.

Comment: Thanks man,
I've just have one more question. I followed the 2nd option you said however I can't get the plane where the text is written on to get the shirt's shape. How can I do that man?

Comment: I think you misunderstood . It should be a plane extruded from shirt mesh during the modelling process. So that the shape is same. If you are not a modeller or its a ready made model then follow other 2 options. Note:make a new material for each player.